# para que sirve #ifdef_MSDOS_ en c++?

Tags: c++

He tenido problemas porque donde trabajo usan una versión de dev c++ 4.9    y yo uso en mi hogar la 5.1, he buscado en internet que inserte en el código como cabecera #ifdef... , alguien me puede decir como usarlo y si puede solucionar mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Es un condicional, para que el código solo se compile bajo determinadas condiciones, en este caso sería para que ese código solo se compile si estás en un entorno con MSDOS

[Descripción aqui](http://sopa.dis.ulpgc.es/fso/cpp/intro_c/introc94.htm)

Si que lo puedes usar, dado que puedes definir un simbolo tu mismo (En el entorno donde quieres que se ejecute tu código) y que el código solo se compile cuando lo tengas definido.

**NOTA:** Esto no hará que tu código sea compatible, sino que no se compile en determinados casos

Answer (score 1):

`#ifdef` es una directiva del precompilador que permite realizar compilaciones condicionales. Su sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
// opción 1
#ifdef [NOMBRE]
  [código1]
#endif

// opción 2
#ifdef [NOMBRE]
  [código1]
#else
  [código2]
#endif
```

Y significa lo siguiente: "Si [NOMBRE] es un identificador que existe entonces compila el fragmento [código1]. En caso contrario compila el fragmento (si procede) [código2]".

Para definir identificadores puedes hacer uso de la directiva `#define` tal y como se aprecia en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#define COMPILA_1

#ifdef COMPILA_1
int func()
{ return 1; }
#else
int func()
{ return 2; }
#endif

int main()
{
  int valor = func();
  printf("%d\n",valor);
}
```

Si lo compilas tal cual está, imprimirá `1`, ya que el identificador existe. Sin embargo, si comentas la línea del `#define` el identificador dejará de existir y el programa, después de recompilarlo, imprimirá `2`.

Hay que destacar que los compiladores suelen definir algunas constantes en función del entorno sobre el que están corriendo (Windows/Linux, 32/64 bits, ...).

En tu caso, se ve que el código que te da problemas únicamente falla (o funciona, porque no queda muy claro) si estás compilando bajo el entorno MSDOS. Añadiendo la compilación condicional podrás eliminar el código dañino al compilar el programa en un entorno que no soporta esas instrucciones.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

#### [¿Qué significa `#ifdef`?](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional)

La instrucción `#ifdef` es una directiva de [preprocesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocesador) que comprueba si una definición de preprocesador existe. Su área de influencia empieza en la instrucción `#ifdef` y perdura hasta dar con la instrucción `#endif`, pudiendo añadir opcionalmente la forma negada `#else` o una condición adicional mediante `#elif`.

#### ¿Qué es el preprocesador?

El preprocesador es un programa ajeno al compilador que se encarga de realizar una serie de operaciones sobre el código **antes** de que el compilador intente compilar. Preprocesador y compilador son programas diferentes<sup>1</sup> y no interactúan entre si; simplemente el preprocesador prepara el código para el compilador y entonces el compilador lo usa.

#### ¿Qué hace `#ifdef`?

Activa o desactiva las líneas dentro de su área de influencia acordes a si la condición se cumple o incumple. Así que por ejemplo:

```
int main() {
#ifdef FABADA
    int asturiana = 0xfabada;
#else
    std::string patatas_fritas { "Que ricas!" };
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

En el código anterior el `#ifdef` está comprobando la existencia de la definición `FABADA`; si existe el preprocesador activará las líneas entre `#ifdef` y `#else` mientras que desactivará las líneas entre `#else` y `#endif`, así que enviará al compilador el siguiente código:

```
int main() {
    int asturiana = 0xfabada;
    return 0;
}
```

En caso de que la definición `FABADA` no exista las líneas activadas/desactivadas serán las contrarias y el preprocesador enviará al compilador el siguiente código:

```
int main() {
    std::string patatas_fritas { "Que ricas!" };
    return 0;
}
```

#### Suena interesante pero ¿qué es `#ifdef_MSDOS_`?

En el título tienes `#ifdef_MSDOS_` sin espacios entre el `#ifdef` y `_MSDOS_` lo que asumo que es una errata porque no funciona :)

Lo que está comprobando es si la definición `_MSDOS_` existe para activar o desactivar líneas de código en conseciencia.

#### Entonces ¿De dónde viene la definición `_MSDOS_`?

Estas definiciones pueden venir de tres sitios distintos:

- Definido por el usuario mediante la instrucción [`#define`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace).
- Definido por el usuario desde línea de comandos (generalmente mediante el parámetro `D`, por ejemplo `-D_MSDOS_`).
- Definido por el compilador.

Si en alguna parte del código escribes:

```
#define _MSDOS_
```

Creas esa definición del preprocesador y cualquier comprobación sobre la existencia de dicha definición será verdadera (siempre y cuando la definición sea visible desde el punto en que se hace la comprobación). En algunas ocasiones se le asigna un valor a la definición:

```
#define _MSDOS_ 5
```

Pero es indiferente de cara al `#ifdef`, ya que este comprueba si (`if`) está definido (`def`) no si tiene valor; para hacer una comprobación respecto a valor se usa la instrucción `#if`:

```
#define _MSDOS_ 5
    std::cout << 
#if _MSDOS_ == 3
    "Microsoft DOS Version 3\n";
#elif _MSDOS_ == 5
    "Microsoft DOS Version 5\n";
#endif
```

Consigues el mismo efecto si al compilar añades la definición en la línea de comandos del compilador:

> C:\proyectos\mi_proyecto> compila main.cpp -D_MSDOS_

Con la diferencia que la definición aplicada desde línea de comandos será visible en todos los archivos en lugar de sólo los que puedan ver la instrucción `#define _MSDOS_`.

Finalmente, los compiladores predefinen varias definiciones de procesador para dar información al usuario, como versión del compilador, sistema operativo, versión del estándar de C++, etc...

Aquí tienes las definiciones predefinidas de algunos compiladores:

- [Microsoft VC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b0084kay.aspx).
- [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html) (Inglés).

#### ¿De dónde viene la definición `_MSDOS_`?, segunda parte.

He mirado en las definiciones predefinidas de varios compiladores y no he visto que ninguno haga referencia a `_MSDOS_`, así que deduzco que esa definición es específica de tu proyecto; seguramente esté definida en algún archivo de cabecera (extensión `.h` o `.hpp`) o bien se añada desde la línea de comandos.

#### ¿Para qué sirve?

Es difícil asegurarlo con tan poca información, pero deduzco por el nombre que servirá para que el código que compilas sea compatible con [Microsoft DOS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS); lo que me hace pensar que estás tocando código bastante antiguo.

---

<sup>1</sup>Esto no necesariamente es cierto siempre, algunos compiladores incorporan el preprocesador. Pero sigue siendo cierto que preprocesador y compilador trabajan por separado.